# Updating a table in oracle using another table rows

Tags: oracle-10g

I want to update each row of a oracle table based on another table's rows.
To be more specific, 
There's a table called Contact with the following fields:

```
 code(PK), name, mobile, email
```

There's also another table called Contact_Updated with same fields.
The question is how to update Contact records with their equivalent in Contact_Updated table?

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
MERGE INTO Contact a
  USING Contact_Updated b
    ON (a.code = b.code)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN  /* no NOT MATCHED clause, so no inserts, update only */
    UPDATE SET a.name = b.name,  a.mobile=b.mobile,  a.email=b.email;
```